# Extracting content of next and different tag using Beautifulsoup

Tags: html, python-3.x, ubuntu, beautifulsoup

I want to **scrape** some particular peice of html code.

my python code :

```
    soup = '''

            <p>
                <strong> abc </strong>
            </p>

            <ul>
                <li> 123 </li>
                <li> 456 </li>
            </ul>
    '''

    import bs4
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(soup, 'html.parser')
    for link in soup.find_all('strong') :
        k = link.next_sibling
        print (link.text)
        print (k)
        print (k.text)
```

and output :

```
    abc

    AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'
```

How can i extract "123" and "456" using above tags?

Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many solutions, for example, you can combine `find_next()` and `find_next_sibling()` methods:

```
soup = '''

        <p>
            <strong> abc </strong>
        </p>

        <ul>
            <li> 123 </li>
            <li> 456 </li>
        </ul>
'''

import bs4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(soup, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('strong') :
    li1 = link.find_next().li
    li2 = li1.find_next_sibling()
    print(link.text)
    print(li1.text)
    print(li2.text)
```

Prints:

```
 abc 
 123 
 456
```

Answer (score 0):

You wanted `123` and `456` so you can use :has and `:contains` (bs4 4.7.1+) to target the parent `p` having the child `strong` with text `'abc'`, then use an adjacent sibling combinator with type selector to get the adjacent `ul`; finally use a child combinator with `li` type selector to get the child `li` elements.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''

            <p>
                <strong> abc </strong>
            </p>

            <ul>
                <li> 123 </li>
                <li> 456 </li>
            </ul>
    '''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
print([i.text for i in soup.select('p:has(>strong:contains("abc")) + ul > li')])
```

Read about css selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

Answer (score 0):

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 
html = '''<div><p>
                <strong> abc </strong>
            </p>
            <ul>
                <li> 123 </li>
                <li> 456 </li>
            </ul></div>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
s = doc.strong # doc.getElementByTag('strong')
lis = s.parent.next.children
print(s.text) 
print(lis[0].text) 
print(lis[1].text)
```

result:

```
abc
123
456
```